# How to display image meta data on toast when clicking Gallery in android using Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, gallery

I am trying to develop an app to display images meta data i.e. `ImageName`, `ImagePath`, `CapturingDate`, `Size`, extension. I want to to use `Broadcast Receiver` and whenever I open `Gallery` and click on any image it shows all its data in a `Toast`. Please anybody can help me?

```
public class CameraEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Uri imageUri;
String getimgname, getimgpath;
private DatabaseHelper dbhelp;  

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            dbhelp = new DatabaseHelper(context);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int s = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            int m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DATE);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);  
            intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "IMG"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(photo));
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            getimgname = photo.getName();
            getimgpath = photo.getAbsolutePath();
            String time = Integer.toString(h) + ":" + Integer.toString(m);
            String date = Integer.toString(day) + "/" + Integer.toString(month) + "/" + Integer.toString(year);
            db.delete("camera", null, null);
             ContentValues imageValues = new ContentValues();
                imageValues.put("imgname", getimgname);
                imageValues.put("imgpath", getimgpath);
                imageValues.put("imgtime", time);       
                imageValues.put("imgdate", date);
                db.insert("camera", null, imageValues);
                new actmon().camera = true; 
                Toast.makeText(context, getimgname+"\n"+getimgpath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} }
```

I have tried this code for taking picture using android native camera and I stored some of its meta data on database. This code is working perfectly. Now i am trying to to click on image and show its meta data on Toast. The question is how can I access android native gallery using broadcast receiver.

Comment: What have you tried? What's blocking you? We will not do your work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added extra information in existing question I think you will get my point.